# BUG: Problems generating FEM ElementMesh in 1-D

Tags: bugs, mesh, finite-element-method

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

I'm trying to build an `ElementMesh` for a simple 1-D problem.

First, I build the boundary `ElementMesh`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{0}, {5}, {10}},
  "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[List /@ #, #] &@Range@3}
  ]
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]]
```

and this apparently works as expected:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I try to build the full `ElementMesh`:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh,
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{2.5}, 1, 0.1}, {{7.5}, 2, 0.2}}
  ]
```

and this doesn't works:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I don't add markers in the first step:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> {{0}, {5}, {10}},
  "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[List /@ Range@3]}
  ]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh,
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{2.5}, 1}, {{7.5}, 2}}
  ]
```

the full ElementMesh is built:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but the region markers are not assigned:

```
Show[
 bmesh["Wireframe"],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried using "BoundaryMarkerFunction" option but I was unsuccessfull.

Comment: Don't forget to report it to WR (@user21 are from WR?)

Comment: OK, this is fixed in current sources and once a new version of Mathematica becomes available, then this will work as you'd expect. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an bug in the 1D case. A somewhat cumbersome way to work around that is to generate the mesh and then generate the mesh a second time where markers are computed and inserted into the mesh elements:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0}, {5}, {10}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[List /@ Range@3]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];

mkMarker[c_, inci_] := Module[{pt1 = #[[1, 1]], pt2 = #[[2, 1]]},
    Which[
     pt2 <= 5, 1,
     pt1 >= 5, 2,
     True, 4 ]] & /@ (c[[#]] & /@ inci)

mkLineEle[c_, le_LineElement] := 
 LineElement[ElementIncidents[le], mkMarker[c, ElementIncidents[le]]]

coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
m2 = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "MeshElements" -> (mkLineEle[coords, #] & /@ mesh["MeshElements"]),
   "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[
      Flatten[Position[coords, #]] & /@ bmesh["Coordinates"], {7, 5, 8}]}
   ];

Show[
 m2["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]], 
 m2["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red]]]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug. Hope this will be solved soon, because refering to markers for i.e. physical properties of the medium is very useful provided it is simple to assign markers.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in **10.1** (windows)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0}, {5}, {10}}, 
"BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[List /@ #, #] &@Range@3}]
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]]

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{2.5}, 1, 0.1}, {{7.5}, 2, 0.2}}]
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"], 
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]], 
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red]]]
```